# How can I stop auto-joining the 'Rookie Help' chat channel?

Tags: eve-online

Every time I log into EVE Online, I am autojoined to multiple chat channels including 'Corp' and 'Rookie Help';

[image]

How can I change it so I no longer join the 'Rookie Help' channel?

Comment: If you need to ask, are you sure you ought to be leaving the channel?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz cheeky! The reason I ask is the Rookie Help channel in EVE is akin to General/Trade Chat in WoW

Comment: Nah, it's not that bad; unless trade chat has gotten significantly better in the past two years and rookie help has gotten significantly worse. In any case, you will stop autojoining (and lose the ability to join altogether) after your first month.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After your initial thirty days, you will no longer be able to join Rookie Help.

I don't think it's possible to stop autojoining the channel prematurely; the best you can do is to manually close it every time you log in.

Comment: You can right-clic it and select "blink off" too, if you want the channel to stop reminding you that it's still there...